# The name 'GetInvestPeriod' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.net solution, which contains a project **InvestTracking** where I am calling a function `GetInvestPeriod()` from the `PageLoad` event.
I have another project **InvestTrackingBL** which contains the function `GetInvestPeriod()`.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetInvestPeriod();
}  

public class InvestTrackingBL
{
    protected void GetInvestPeriod()
    {

    }
}
```

I am getting an error in my main project:

> 'The name *GetInvestPeriod* does not exist in the current context'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: A method is not contained in a project. A method is contained in a type. While a type has been defined in a project. Hence, giving us the definiton of the type, in which you have defined the method called `GetInvestPeriod`, we could help.

Comment: The most common cause is that the namespace that defines the "InvestTrackingBL" class is missing. Identify and import the required namespace in your class.

Comment: This question is somewhat rudimentary that arguably would have been explained in any _Welcome to Visual Studio_ 101 book or tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just use the function like that.

You either need an instance of `InvestTrackingBL` or call the static method on it:

```
//If it's an instance member
var investTrackingBL = new InvestTrackingBL();
investTrackingBL.GetInvestPeriod();

//or if it's static
InvestTrackingBL.GetInvestPeriod();
```

And following your update. Methods that are `protected` cannot be called by other classes, only derived classes, you need to make it `public` or `internal`.